# def function producing incorrect output

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

My task is to:

Write a function, `starts_with(word, chs)` that returns whether or not the string word begins with one of the characters in the list `chs`.

If word is an empty string, return `False`.

If `chs` is an empty list, return `False`.

I'm passing 6/7 test cases except for one which shows an Assertion error, however, I don't know what input is being used in each test case so I can't figure out the issue. What could the issue be?

```
def starts_with(word, chs):
    x = 0
    if (len(chs)== 0) or (word == ""):
        return (False)
    while x < len(chs):
        s = word[0]
        if s == chs[x]: {
        }
        x += 1
        return (True)

word = ()
chs = ()
```

Comment: What are the curly brackets after the second if statement?

Comment: The whole part inside the `while` loop is wonky. Python doesn't use `{}` like other languages to indicate scope, and you don't have anything inside of the `if` either. This looks like it will return True no matter what as long as the very first check is False

Comment: Also note: those last two assignments word = ... and chs = ... just make no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try approaching this task using the proper Python builtin functions rather than apply C/Java-style programming. It is way more readable.

Using `string.startswith()`:

```
def starts_with(word, chs):
    for c in chs:
        if word.startswith(c):
            return True
    return False #you can avoid this line, it will return None by default
```

Another way would be to check if the first letter of `word` is in `chs`:

```
def f(word, chs):
    if word and chs and word[0] in chs:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def starts_with(word, chs):
        if (len(chs)== 0) or (word == ""):
            return False
        elif word[0] in chs:
            return True
```

an update:

```
def starts_with(word, chs):
    if not word: return False
    elif word[0] in chs:
        return True
```